# Редирект с .html страницы на .php или перевод правил apache в nginx

Tags: php, html, wordpress, apache, nginx

Есть такие правила для apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^rtest.html$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/test.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blackping.html$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/blackping.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^logout.html$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/logout.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^curscron.html$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/curscron.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/sitemap.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^exportxml.xml$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/exportxml.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^exporttxt.txt$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/exporttxt.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Один из редиректов для nginx:

```
location = /curscron.html {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/curscron.php break;
}
```

Вместо выполнения /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/curscron.php, появляется окно, где предлагается сохранить файл.

Comment: Откройте codex, там есть набор правил для nginx. У вас не подключен upstream, потому отдаётся файл

Comment: Хм... при прямом обращении /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/curscron.php, все норм. При rewrite сохраняется curscron.html, но с кодом curscron.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя мой [хитрозадуманный конвертер Apache->NGINX](https://www.getpagespeed.com/apache-to-nginx):

```
index index.php;
rewrite ^/rtest.html$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/test.php last;
rewrite ^/blackping.html$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/blackping.php last;
rewrite ^/logout.html$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/logout.php last;
rewrite ^/curscron.html$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/curscron.php last;
rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/sitemap.php last;
rewrite ^/exportxml.xml$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/exportxml.php last;
rewrite ^/exporttxt.txt$ /wp-content/plugins/exchangebox/sitepage/exporttxt.php last;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: Да, именно так все отлично стало работать!